# Extending a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match javascript files inside `/static/js` that include `?v=xxxx` at the end, 'x' being a character or a number, so it has to match:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/static/js/components/backbone.js?v=a6tsb
```

But not:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/static/js/views/ribbon.js
http://127.0.0.1:8888/templates/require-config.js
```

This one matches the hash:

```
var hashRegex = new RegExp("^.*\\?v=\\w{5}$");
```

But I'm trying to extend that one to include "/static/js".

I tried:

```
var hashRegex = new RegExp("^.*\/static\/js\/.*\\?v=\\w{5}$");
```

But doesn't seems to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you need to escape your forward slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript when regex is represented using string you need to double escape(`\\`) the special character(of regex)

So,your regex would be

```
var hashRegex = new RegExp("^.*/static/js/.*\\?v=\\w{5}$");
```

---

But if you use this syntax for regex

```
var hashRegex = /regex/;
```

you have to escape with single `\`.You would also escape `/` since it is used as a delimiter

So,your regex in this case would be

```
var hashRegex = /^.*\/static\/js\/.*\?v=\w{5}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
var hashRegex = new RegExp("^.*\/static\/js\/.*\?v\=[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$");
```

( I don't know if you have to escape the = )